# Dates before January 1st, 1970

Tags: java

The [getTime()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) fetches the time in millis for a certain Date. Can this be used reliably for dates say in the 18th century. We use the millis and store it in a string variable for future comparison. Is there a limit on how far in the past that this could be used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would highly recommend you take a look at [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) if you are doing date/time comparisons of the distant past. Or actually any sort of date/time comparisons and calculations. It is a great library!

Don't rely on getTime() for what you want to do. At least consider using Java's [Calendar/GregorianCalendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).  But personally, I'd suggest using JodaTime.

Comment: Calendar too uses the *Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT* — so I wonder if a Calendar could handle my birthday. Let alone distant distant past.

Comment: use java.time (JSR-310) since Java 8

Answer (score 12):

Of course, long is signed and for example 1.1.1701 is -8 488 782 000 000.

Answer (score 2):

**Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object**

Better to go for [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) OR [Jodatime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)