# Data type for storing a date prior to 1970-01-01

Tags: java, date, jodatime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dates before January 1st, 1970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706937/dates-before-january-1st-1970)

I'm looking for a standard solution for storing a date that may have a value earlier than 1970-01-01. Joda-time based solution is appreciated.

For example, I want to store a release date of an album "The Voice of Frank Sinatra", which is March 4, 1946.

Comment: @Keppil Nope. The answer there doesn't include info on how to use Joda  Time for that, nor does the question

Comment: So what is stopping you from using JodaTime? There is no difference for recent dates before 1970 as after.

Comment: I don't see much problems here. Even `new java.util.GregorianCalendar 1946, 2, 4)` can do it.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: Yes it does, look again.

Comment: `System.out.println(new org.joda.time.DateTime(1946, 3, 4, 0, 0));`

Comment: @Keppil I don't consider a link to a site as explanation on how to use something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to store a release date of an album "The Voice of Frank Sinatra", which is March 4, 1946.

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(1948, 3, 4);
System.out.println(date);
```

prints

```
1948-03-04
```

LocalDate can be used for any year from 1 AD or 1 CE and assumes a Gregorian Calendar by default.

Comment: Could you please explain why `LocalDate` is more appropriate than `DateTime` for that, if it is?

Comment: LocalDate is just a date. DateTime is a date and a time and is more appropriate if you also want to store a time as well. Assuming some notional time of day is more misleading than useful IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1946, 3, 4, 0, 0);
```

calling `dt.getMillis()` will then just yield a negative number.