# android: Is it possible to add google calendar event before 1/1/1970?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to add recurrence event (birthday) before 1.1.1970 by code.
I know that the start time of event in google calendar is in epoch time.
Someone know?
Is it possible?
I mean in google calendar API. not in java itself

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dates before January 1st, 1970](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706937/dates-before-january-1st-1970)

Comment: @DalmTo, yes, I tried. the event is not created well

Comment: Ok, I got it. I use start-time in minus values!