# spark-sql builtin dayofmonth function returning weird results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For some strange reason , the `dayofmonth` function in spark seems to return strange value for years `1500 or less`.

Following were the results that was obtained  ->

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT dayofmonth('1501-02-14') ").show()
+------------------------------------+
|dayofmonth(CAST(1501-02-14 AS DATE))|
+------------------------------------+
|                                  14|
+------------------------------------+


scala> spark.sql("SELECT dayofmonth('1500-02-14') ").show()
+------------------------------------+
|dayofmonth(CAST(1500-02-14 AS DATE))|
+------------------------------------+
|                                  13|
+------------------------------------+


scala> spark.sql("SELECT dayofmonth('1400-02-14') ").show()
+------------------------------------+
|dayofmonth(CAST(1400-02-14 AS DATE))|
+------------------------------------+
|                                  12|
+------------------------------------+
```

Can anyone explain , why spark behaves this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because dates are exposed externally as `java.sql.Date` and are represented internally as the number of dates since the **Unix epoch** (1970-01-01).

**References:** [source 1](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a2a41b7bf2bfdcd1cff242013716ac7bd84bdacd/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala#L38), [source 2](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a2a41b7bf2bfdcd1cff242013716ac7bd84bdacd/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/datetimeExpressions.scala#L413) and [3](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2761).

This mainly creates lots of issues when dealing with dates before 1970 but you can try creating `udf`s (I can't believe I'm writing this) with external libraries that might be able to cope with this problem as adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706937/dates-before-january-1st-1970).

*Reminder:* Of course, you need to take into account performance bottlenecks using `udf`s. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance).

For more information about Unix Time, you can read the following :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time